# Null Pointer Exception using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

I am trying to automate and have integrated Selenium with Appium and I am using Eclipse with TestNG for execution.

Now within a project I have a package with two classes; the first class is for login into the App and the second class is for logout

First class code -

```
    package com.gma.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class LoginApp {
        public AppiumDriver driver;

        @BeforeSuite
        public void beforeMethod() throws InterruptedException {

            File app = new File("C:\\Users\\mc30058\\Downloads\\gma-QA-RELEASE-QRCode-07022015_v4.5.4028.apk");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='com.mcdonalds.app:id/button_choose_closest']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Continue']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='OK']")).click();

        }

        @Test (priority=1)
        public void Login() {

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign In']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.mcdonalds.app:id/signin_edittext_email']")).sendKeys("anuj.shrivastava@us.mcd.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.mcdonalds.app:id/signin_edittext_password']")).sendKeys("Anujtest2");

            currentTime();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Sign In']")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Yeah, count me in!']")).isDisplayed();
            currentTime();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='No, thanks. I like to be out of the loop']")).click();
        }

        private void currentTime() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
        }

    }

Second class code: 

    package com.gma.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class Logout {

        public AppiumDriver driver;




        @Test (priority=3)
        public void LogoutApp() {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Navigation Button']")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign Out']")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Sign Out']")).click();
        }
    }
```

Contents from Testng.xml

```
<suite name = "GMA Automation">
    <test name = "GMA Automation">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.gma.test.LoginApp"/>
            <class name = "com.gma.test.Logout"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I receive Null Pointer exception after execution of first class. Appium server stops saying no more commands received. Please help.

Comment: Could you share the stacktrace?

Comment: If you Provide Stacktrace it will help us to find the problem, but now from your provided  code ,you are  missing the priority no 2 . you had given the logout test case to priority 3 but it will comes to priority 2.  Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE b'coz you have declared one more driver reference `public AppiumDriver driver;` in your Logout class.

And you are using this driver reference without instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

In logout class you forget to instantiate your AppiumDriver driver.

try this:

public AppiumDriver driver;

driver = new AndroidDriver();